# Second Order Homogeneous Differential Equation from Optimal Controls

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Please excuse my moment of ignorance while I reboot my education in math. I am taking an optimal controls course and it has been quite some time since I've worked with calculus.

On to my question...

I have a 2nd order homogeneous differential equation that represents an optimal solution as follows:

$$tx''(t)-3x'(t) = 0$$

For those who are not familiar with controls notation, this equation can be written in classical $x$-$y$ format as such:

$$xy''-3y' = 0$$

What is throwing me off here is the non-constant coefficient before $y''$. I do not remember how to go about solving this and wikipedia is only confusing me further.

Thanks to all in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a first order differential equation in disguise. Let $u = y'$ to get:

$$
x u' - 3 u = 0
$$

This is a separable equation:

$$
\frac{u'}{u} = \frac{3}{x}
$$

Integrate:

$$
\log u = 3 \log x + a_1 = \log x^3 + a_1
$$

Therefore:

$$
u = \exp(\log x^3 + a_1) = b_1 x^3
$$

Where $b_1 = \pm \exp(a_1)$.

Given that $u = y'$, we have:

$$
y' = b_1 x^3
$$

Integrate to get the solution:

$$
y = c_1 x^4 + c_2
$$

Where $c_1 = b_1/4$.

Comment: Hi Ayman. Thanks for the edit and response! Can you explain the part between step 2 and 3?

Comment: @Kashif We just integrate both sides. You know that the integral of $u'/u$ is $\log u$, right?

Comment: No, I don't remember that. I remember that the derivative of $log(u)$ is $1/u$ so then the integral of $u'/u$ would be something else entirely, I think

Comment: @Kashif The derivative of $\log(u)$ is $1/u$ if $u$ is an independent variable. If $u$ is a function of $x$, then the derivative of $\log(u)$ is $u'/u$ by the chain rule.

Comment: Ah, okay. I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: @Kashif You're welcome.